# error while writing new crontab to /var/spool/cron/#tmp.XXXXr9wBsu

Tags: cron

When trying to edit the crontab using `crontab -e` command, I get the
error below:

```
[root@xxxx ~]# crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
crontab: error while writing new crontab to /var/spool/cron/#tmp.XXXXr9wBsu
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.jIxTJI
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the root cause for the  `crontab -e` -> "crontab: error while
writing new crontab" behaviour: this is a space issue.

```
[root@xxxxxx/]# df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootVG-root
                      37573292  19628508  16029496  56% /

tmpfs                  1962336         0   1962336   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               144646     65608     71358  48% /boot

/dev/mapper/rootVG-tmp
                       3869352      8980   3660488   1% /tmp

/dev/mapper/rootVG-var
                      15866832  15850448         0 100% /var
xxxxxx:/d/oss/global

                     300571648 174983168 110313472  62% /d/oss/global
xxxxxx:/home         300571648 174983168 110313472  62% /home
```

Two-year-old logs were accumulated in `/var/log/`, so I cleaned those
up and freed around 20% of the space in `/var`, and can now edit the
crontab.

Comment: some sort of monitoring on disk space might alert you before the filesystem completely fills up...